# How can i load my classes from MySql using ADO.NET framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

Using ASP.NET framework 4.6.1, I installed MYSQL connector/NET 8.0.17

If i try to choose database connection then

> > Authentication to host 'for user' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Access denied for user @192.168.0.2 (Using password: NO)

I have  Entity framework 6.2.0 and mysql.data and mysql.data.entity both are 6.10.9

I have change versions but failed!

Comment: You can't fix a bad password by changing library versions. The error message is clear

Comment: This has nothing to do with the versioning. Read the error message again: it says **access denied**. You need think about how you're doing security... whether the MySql server allows connections from that IP, for that user account, using that authentication type. Probably you need to change the connection string, too.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Can you send me correct connection string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can access database as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here is video https://www.loom.com/share/5b66633b8fc440a2bb165f9635baf569

Comment: @ZubairFarooq I can't possibly know your connection string. It depends on how your server is configured, what account name you want to use, etc. Only you can know what it needs to look like. But you can use http://www.connectionstrings.com to help build one.